# How to Implement Payout Functionality in Django using Stripe API?

Tags: django, django-models, stripe-payments

I am building a Django web application and I want to implement a payout functionality using the Stripe API(test mode). Here's what I need to achieve:

1.User clicks on the "Withdraw" button.

2.User enters their account details (such as bank account number, routing number, etc.)

3. Then transfer the money to that account

I have already installed the Stripe Python library and set up my Stripe API key. How can I achieve this functionality in my Django application? Any guidance on the Django views, forms, and Stripe API integration would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So even though it's not mentioned, I'm assuming this is a Stripe Connect set up - you want your Connected Account users to be able to add an external_account, then payout funds from their available Stripe balance to this account ?

This is how I'd suggest doing it:

> 2.User enters their account details (such as bank account number, routing number, etc.)

This would be custom fields*, which you then use the value of to form into a Stripe Token with the frontend function `createToken`:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens/create_token?type=bank_account

You would then attach the bank account Token to your Connected Account's `external_accounts`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-external_account

> 3.Then transfer the money to that account

Finally, you can make a Payout of any available funds using this call [0]:

```
stripe.Payout.create(
  amount=amount,
  currency=currency,
  stripe_account=acct_id # your connected account ID [1]
)
```

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create?lang=python
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

*Note that Stripe has some elements to render fields for specific bank account types (e.g. IBAN element):
https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/other_element?type=iban

Comment: "When I create the "external_accounts" function, this error is shown. What should I do?" - Stripe Error: Request req_THLW0m1rAKfzt4: Only live keys can access this method

Comment: I think that means you're trying to do this for Standard accounts. You can't add external_accounts on them, only Express / Custom. Standard account users add their own bank accounts through Stripe's onboarding / dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can't "send money" to a bank account like that without first onboarding them via Connect in order to perform identity verification. You can read about creating & onboarding Express accounts [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-account).

You should review the Connect docs, such as [this pay out money guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#with-code-pay-out-to-user), to see how you can achieve this.

Once you have onboarded connected accounts, you can optionally look at creating [manual payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts), and doing that in python for some connected account with a balance looks like this:

```
stripe.Payout.create(
  amount=1000,
  currency="usd",
  stripe_account='{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
)
```